# Jacobi symbol $\left(\frac{(n+1)/2}{n}\right)$

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-reciprocity, legendre-symbol

Let $(\frac{a}{n})_J$ be Jacobi symbol defined by
\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{a}{n}\right)_J=\left(\frac{a}{p_1}\right)^{e_1}\left(\frac{a}{p_2}\right)^{e_2}\cdots\left(\frac{a}{p_k}\right)^{e_k}
\end{equation}

where $n=p_1^{e_1}p_2^{e_2}\cdots p_k^{e_k}$ is the prime factorization of $n$ and $(\frac{a}{p})$ is Legendre symbol.

I want to prove that for odd integer $n$
\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{(n+1)/2}{n}\right)_J=\left\{
                                    \begin{array}{ll}
                                    (-1)^{\frac{n-1}{4}},  &  n=1 ~mod~~4 \\
                                    (-1)^{\frac{n+1}{4}}, &   n=3 ~mod~~4.\
                                    \end{array}
                             \right.
\end{equation}

Thanks in advance. Happy new year.

Comment: Hint: $$\left(\frac{4}{n}\right)_J = 1$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use known information about the value of  $\left(\frac{a}{n}\right)_J\left(\frac{b}{n}\right)_J$, in the case $a=2$, $b=(n+1)/2$. Use also known information about the value of $\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)_J$.